# Can an asp:DropDownList set to be displayed in a particular direction; up or down?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, drop-down-menu, direction

Is it possible to set the direction that an asp:DropDownList appears on a page (e.g. up or down) in a code-behind/with javascript irrespective of how a browser will render it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't manipulate it's behaviour, but you can emulate dropdown lists with javascript, likely with a framework (jQuery, ExtJS, etc.).

Comment: but be careful changing the default behaviours of standard browser elements - users are used to them.

Comment: I agree...that's one of my big UI hates. Just look at all the UI broken flash apps out there...

Comment: Thanks @erenon.

@edeverett: Very good point.

This will have to go down as a "known issue"